# Continue inserting data in temporary table when met exception in SQL Server 2005 (also for 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have 2 simple tables

```
+------|---------|----------+
+  ID  |  Value  |   Test   +
+------|---------|----------+
+  3   |   Test  |   12345  +
+  4   |  MyVal  |   56789  +
+  5   |  Another|   101010 +
+------|---------|----------+



+------|---------|----------+
+  ID  |  Value  |   Test   +
+------|---------|----------+
+  3   |   Test  |   12345  +
+  7   |  MyVal12|   56789  +
+  5   |  Another|   101010 +
+------|---------|----------+
```

The `ID` from both tables are primary keys.

In my stored procedure, I create a temporary table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable(
        ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
        FIELD VARCHAR(255))
```

and the part of my procedure stored with `try-catch` block:

```
BEGIN TRY
INSERT INTO #tempTable(ID, FIELD)
EXEC sp_executesql @myCustomSql, @paramList, @param1, @param2 ...
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
      // what to put here ?
END CATCH
```

I want to add rows to my temporary table (you'll see the duplicates for ID = 3 and 5) and I want to continue adding. Finally I want to have the following content for table:

```
+------|---------+
+  ID  |  FIELD  +
+------|---------+
+  3   |   Test  +
+  4   |  MyVal  +
+  5   |  Another+ 
+  7   |  MyVal12+
+------|---------+
```

I gave here a simplified example, in my database I have over one hundred thousand rows and many columns.

Thanks

Comment: Does `CREATE TABLE #tempTable(ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED  WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON), FIELD VARCHAR(255))` do what you need?

Comment: Yes, good solution. You can move this comment and make an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ignore (with a warning) attempts to insert duplicate keys rather than raising an error and having the whole statement fail you can use the [`IGNORE_DUP_KEY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186869.aspx) option.

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable
  (
     ID    INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON),
     FIELD VARCHAR(255)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just put a UNION into the @myCustomSQL between the two tables to filter out duplicates?

If not then maybe a GOTO would be the best for you,

```
DECLARE @minID int;
SET @minID = 0;

-- Ensure your myCustomerSql only gets records with ID greater than @minID

:CarryOn

BEGIN TRY
INSERT INTO #tempTable(ID, FIELD)
EXEC sp_executesql @myCustomSql, @paramList, @param1, @param2 ...
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 2627 -- Error code for duplicate key
    THEN
        SET @min_ID = SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 FROM #TempTable;
        GOTO CarryOn
    ELSE
        --Handle other errors somehow
END CATCH
```

I wouldn't normally recommend anything as messy as that but you obviously have dirty data already so I'd hope this is a once off to repair it.